# How to hide Wordpress users' names externally?

Tags: users

I have several users creating posts in Wordpress, but I don't want any of their names to appear publicly. On the site, I want it to only say By: Website Editor.

This also means that the names should not appear in any other related URLs, for example author URLs. If someone were to visit [www.example.com/?author=3](http://www.example.com/?author=3) for example, it should not reveal any names. I don't mind disabling author URLs completely if that's easier to do.

The SEO plugin I use also shows the name of the author in the source, that's gotta go away also.

And in the backend, the names should appear just like usual.

How could I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can probably just hook `get_the_author_user_nicename` and return `Website Editor`. If that breaks things in the backend then only register the filter if not is_admin() or is DOING_AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can best be achieved with a plugin, as it requires changing certain data stored in the database.

Comment: I don't think it does? I should think all of this could be done with filters.

Comment: What plugin did you use in the end out of interest?

Comment: The plugin is called Edit Author Slug. It takes care of changes that cannot be done through Wordpress Admin interface alone, like changing the author's slug in their author URL. I am not sure filters would affect the URL, but in either case, the plugin offers a more permanent solution.